Pytorch dataloader with numpy memmap file
I have a large dataset saved as a .npy file. The data is larger than the available RAM, so loading the entire dataset at once is not possible. I would like to use PyTorch’s Dataset and DataLoader to create small batches and iterate over them. My pipeline works when I use a single worker (num_workers=0), but it fails when I set num_workers > 0.
I found some suggestions online, one of which was to add np.load(file, mmap_mode='r') inside the getitem method in the PyTorch Dataset.
I tried this solution, but it still didn’t work. I am wondering if someone could help me solve this issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
